How to relate the degree of oxidation with the C/O ratio for the nanomaterials like graphene oxide?
I am currently working on the molecular modelling of Graphene oxide. It has different oxygen containing surface functionalities, so different degrees of oxidation. I am wondering if there is anyway to relate the degree of oxidation with the C/O ratio which is usually reported in the literature. So, by 25% degree of oxidation, it means that 25 out of 100 carbon are oxidised. But, clearly, if there are carboxylic groups attached at the edges, it will contribute to two oxygens per carbon atom, so different C/O ratio. Is there any mathematical or a crude way to relate these terms as per the number and the types of oxygenated groups involved. Thanks.

+1 Welcome to our community.
